# Convert SUMIFS to SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel

This is my `SUMIFS` which `SUM` the number in `D12:D1000` if the number in `E12:E1000` is within 21 to 30.

```
SUMIFS(D$12:$D$1000,E$12:$E$1000,">20",E$12:$E$1000,"<31")
```

I tried to convert it to `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
SUMPRODUCT(D12:D1000*(E12:E1000=">20")*(E12:E1000="<31"))
```

But I get 0 as the result. The formula doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your SUMPRODUCT formula should written like this,

=SUMPRODUCT (-- (A2 :A11 >=20),--(A2 :A20<=30),C2 :C20)

Please change data range as you need.